# Correct TimeMapping of AVComposition

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcomposition

I have an `AVComposition` with multiple segments and variable speed, I want to get the proper `CMTime` of a position of the video.

If I do:

```
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(duration.value * position, duration.timescale);
```

The time is not proper as the composition varies in speed, I've been days trying and I cannot find how to do it.

I also tried using `samplePresentationTimeForTrackTime` but what it does is mapping the TARGET ( Composition ) time to the SOURCE ( Asset ) time, I need the opposite, map a position which I know on the SOURCE ( Asset ) to the mapped position on the TARGET ( Composition ).

Any ideas?